# Prioritize Bulk Apex Jobs in the queue

Tags: apex, bulk-api

I have an AWS Lambda that bulk uploads data into SFDC. I can monitor the status of recent bulk data load jobs through the following interface:

In Setup > Environments > Jobs > Bulk Data Load Jobs

These jobs are created by Data Loader and other Bulk API client applications.

Because these jobs are all queued at the same time, how can I set priorities? There is a specific job that I want to take precedence over the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. The Bulk API has no notion of relative priority among jobs. If you need a particular job to run first, you have to orchestrate creation order amongst your various client applications, as well as doing any job-status monitoring you need to do in order to kick off the jobs in your preferred order.